# Mixed strategy that assigns strictly positive weight to a pure strategy that is dominated

Tags: game-theory

This problem is  of Fernando Vega Redondo(Economics and the theory of games)

**Exercise 2.1**
Let G be a game in strategic form. Prove that, for every player
$i\in N$, every mixted strategy $\sigma_{i}\in \Sigma_{i}$ that assigns positive weight to a pure strategy $s_{i}\in S_{i}$ that is dominated can be itself always be improved by another strategy $\sigma_{i}'$.

This is if $s_{i}\in S_{i}$ is strongly dominated for some $\sigma_{i}$$\in \Sigma$
with $\sigma_{i}(s_{i})>0$, $\exists$ $\sigma_{i}'\in \Sigma_{i}$ such that $\forall$$s_{-i}\in S_{-i}$$: \pi_{i}(\sigma_{i}',s_{-i})>\pi_{i}(\sigma_{i},s_{-i})$.

Q1: why they said that affirmation is obvious?

*I would like to know if anyone could tell me how to build a mixed strategy that dominates a strategy that assigns a strictly positive probability to a dominated strategy. It is not obvious to me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The **short answer** is that a mixed strategy $\sigma_i$ that uses with positive probability a dominated pure strategy $s_i$ can always be improved by *excluding* $s_i$ from its mixing support and redistributing its "probability weight" to one of its dominating strategies.

**More formally**, suppose that strategy $s_i'$ dominates $s_i$ (you can think of $s_i'$ as a *pure* or *mixed* strategy itself, this does not make any difference for the argument; for simplicity I suppose $s_i'$ is a pure strategy), that is $\forall s_{-i}\in S_{-i}: \pi(s_i',s_{-i})>\pi(s_i,s_{-i})$.

Also, suppose that strategy $\sigma_i$ plays strategy $s_i$ with positive probability $p_{s_i}\in(0,1)$. Build strategy $\sigma_i'$ as follows: identical to $\sigma_i$ but replace $s_i$ with $s_i'$ , that is play $s_i$ with probability 0 and play $s_i'$ with (additional) probability $p_{s_i}$.

By linearity of the payoff function you have, $\forall s_{-i}\in S_{-i}$:
$$
\pi(\sigma_i',s_{-i})=p_{s_i}\pi(s_i',s_{-i}) + (1-p_{s_i})\pi(\Lambda_i,s_{-i}) > p_{s_i}\pi(s_i,s_{-i}) + (1-p_{s_i})\pi(\Lambda_i,s_{-i}) = \pi(\sigma_i,s_{-i})
$$
where $\Lambda_i$, loosely speaking, denotes the residual combination of strategies played in $\sigma_i$, apart from $s_i$, inherited by $\sigma_i'$ too.